# Calling one service from another service in android

Tags: java, android

My main app starts 2 services Input-service and Save-service. My Input-service is generating input which i am able to show in my Main app and my both services are starting successfully. I am facing problem in calling one service from another. Means how can i send data of Input-service to Save-service. Is there any example which shows communication between two services. Or can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: I have asked a similar question and in the end I settled with using static references to the services.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `BroadcastReceivers`? Register them in `onCreate`, de-register in `onDestroy` and send data through intents ...